# 2001 Hyundai Accent no brake lights/hazards but blinkers work

Tags: brake-light, accent

I have a 2001 Hyundai Accent. The brake lights (L/R/3rd) and hazards DO NOT work but the left hand and right hand turn signal flashers DO work. The headlights and tail lights all DO work also.

We've checked fuses, light bulbs, and replaced the brake light switch. None of that helped.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the stop lamp fuse have power? Is this a 3 or 4 door? Is it an automatic? Does the shift interlock work? Does the hazard relay work?

Comment: It's a 4 door and it is automatic. Is the stop lamp fuse in either the dash fuse box or under hood fuse box? If so, I will say it works because all of the fuses get power with the test light...if it is not one of those fuses, then I will try to find it and check! The shift interlock is interesting because I have to stick a pencil in a hole near the shifter to switch gears...could that have something to do with the brake/hazard lights also? The hazard relay, we do believe it does work.

Comment: The shift interlock is part of the brake switch circuit. So it stands to reason that there's some correlation. Take a look at the wiring diagram SteveRacer provided. The only real difference between 3 and 4 doors are the ground locations.

Comment: Got it. It's raining so we're stuck for today but we are going to try to figure it out tomorrow once weather has cleared. Pretty sure it's pointing to wiring also.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check Fuse #8 in the dash fuse box?  This is a different source of power than the turn/tail lamps.

The diagram below should allow you to figure out where the problem lies.  If Fuse #8 is okay, check for power at the new brake light switch with the brake depressed with a DVOM.  One side always has power; the other side switches the power to the lamps when the pedal closes the switch.

If there is power at both sides of the switch with the pedal depressed and still no brake lights, there is a wiring problem somewhere after the switch.

But I doubt it.  My money is on Fuse #8.

[image]

Comment: I am quite sure we did check fuse 8...we checked all fuses and they all get power with the test light. We replaced the brake light switch also so you may be right with the wiring issue. We will be trying again tomorrow using your all of the information offered so far. Thank y'all for your knowledge. I will keep you updated on any changes or new information!

Comment: Just updating. After a couple of days of rain, we finally got out there to find that the bottom left half of the fuse panel under the dash (fuses # 5-9) is getting extremely low power. It shows to work on test lamp but the volt meter shows barely any power going to those fuses so now we're trying to figure out where the issue is and how to begin. Thanks for directing us to wiring as that is what caused him to check the voltage and such.

Comment: Okay, brake lights/hazards are fixed but only by rigging it temporarily. My bf ran a wire from another fuse to the brake light or hazard fuse that wasn't getting much voltage and it's working. Couldn't figure out a legit way to fix. It works for now. Thanks for y'alls help and information! It led us to the right place.